# How to include Wix Fragments created by Heat

Tags: wix

I have the following fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Doc">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpCDCC386748AE7BEFE7C2F4E764390254" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp6EC513AE37CCAE66CEA96577E2384AFA" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp0C9D9450CB94FF74C6E29C1C3F6D16D5" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp314DEE3E909157F47FDF963DCC04D2AC" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpBC5FB761D7B0DA99F96ECA9A91DD4217" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp6B9E4B7B6F710D7077171BCE0B96A90A" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp5959CF1572C71417D536C491A996C6DE" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpCC960E9F3DDDE1600206003C43FFE663" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="AzureApplicationSDK">
            <Directory Id="dir67745C9C3FA1B31D9AF8883D12D8FBD8" Name="Doc">
                <Component Id="cmpCDCC386748AE7BEFE7C2F4E764390254" Guid="{A46C5689-42D1-41CA-AD71-B2A416FA9571}">
                    <File Id="fil3B7DFCD3444314759F8617411F7EE08C" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Azure Applications SDK v1 Cascade Tables Getting Started Guide.docx" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp6EC513AE37CCAE66CEA96577E2384AFA" Guid="{697C1B04-5279-4B31-9600-F3BCA4C1AD06}">
                    <File Id="filFDDD2C48EF5C14BA924C4272E4D9D490" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Azurite Identity.docx" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp0C9D9450CB94FF74C6E29C1C3F6D16D5" Guid="{1C61C6C5-60F0-41A5-B229-093419E5F767}">
                    <File Id="fil4C736D0525C45780C242DA3BCA6823BA" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Mercurius messaging how-to.docx" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp314DEE3E909157F47FDF963DCC04D2AC" Guid="{FD9BD847-5B89-42EA-A178-451AC8B822F4}">
                    <File Id="fil841FCFCD72670AEF83A89B6724126546" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Nexus Notes.pptx" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpBC5FB761D7B0DA99F96ECA9A91DD4217" Guid="{2424B541-D40B-4D2D-938E-0AC5C9C2A773}">
                    <File Id="fil8D9E68E77FC45E6F50191FF6F20F2039" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Owner Powershell Snapin.docx" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp6B9E4B7B6F710D7077171BCE0B96A90A" Guid="{E467FD03-EFB4-4E4F-9A34-75540BEB1B1C}">
                    <File Id="filB48A598247AE4A63638F96A69A545EE4" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\SDK First Look.pptx" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmp5959CF1572C71417D536C491A996C6DE" Guid="{27890FBC-2822-4061-A086-E9E539F58A64}">
                    <File Id="fil9CCA5FE9338BD9EB6E1E2B4F685D9F16" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Unit Tests.docx" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="cmpCC960E9F3DDDE1600206003C43FFE663" Guid="{D9B8BFB9-3F3B-40FE-A3E9-C5E1669E529A}">
                    <File Id="fil98D1506B9A1C3AD2D9D03EA43BEEB80A" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Using Nexus.docx" />
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Within my main .wxs file I have the following:

```
<Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="zure Application SDK" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="Doc"/>
</Feature>
```

I execute

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3\bin\Light.exe -cultures:null -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3\bin\WixUIExtension.dll" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3\bin\WixNetFxExtension.dll" -out "c:\source\Azure Applications SDK\Bespin\QADrop\QADropInstaller\bin\Release\QADropInstaller.msi" -pdbout "c:\source\Azure Applications SDK\Bespin\QADrop\QADropInstaller\bin\Release\QADropInstaller.wixpdb" -v obj\Release\QADropInstall.wixobj obj\Release\Doc.wixobj
```

and I get the following error

```
Error   21  Unresolved reference to symbol 'Component:Doc' in 
section 'Product:{CF56D65B-BE0D-4719-BEFD-5DC04F7AD7FC}'.   
c:\source\Azure Applications SDK\Bespin\QADrop\QADropInstaller\QADropInstall.wxs
160 1   Azure Application SDK Installer
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 74):

The heat `Fragment` should have a `ComponentGroup` with all of the generated `Components` in it (if not, try adding the `-cg` switch to heat).

Then use a `ComponentGroupRef` instead of a `ComponentRef` under the `Feature` you want everything installed.

Finally, compile all your `.wxs` files (including the one from `heat.exe`) then add all the resultant `.wixobj` files to your `light.exe` command-line. The error you list usually occurs because you forgot to add a `.wixobj` or `.wixlib` to the command-line.